# Tensorflow freeze_graph does not work when

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow, export

I want to freeze a graph as follows, with input_binary set to true:

```
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph = model_path +'/raw_graph_def.pb', input_binary = True, input_checkpoint = last_checkpoint, output_node_names = "action", output_graph = model_path +'/your_name_graph.bytes' , clear_devices = True, initializer_nodes = "",input_saver = "", restore_op_name = "save/restore_all", filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0")
```

For input_checkpoint = last_checkpoint, is the path to the ckpt file meant? That's the one I am using.

Every time I export, i get the error Message:

google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

There is no problem if I leave input_binary = False, but I need it to be true, as I want to export it to Unity.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?